# how to join 2 dimensional array of string in c#?

Tags: c#, join, multidimensional-array

i have problem:

```
string[,] a = string[27,27];
a = bootsrapMinor(data);
string[,] b = string[27,27];
b = bootstrapMayor(data);

string[,] c = a + b;
```

the error message is "Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string[*,*]' and 'string[*,*]'    "

anyone have solutions for my problem in joining 2 dimensional array if string? thanks alot.

Comment: Give an example of the final join? Do you want to concatenate strings at the same positions in the arrays?

Comment: example: a = {"a","b","c","d"},   b = {"e","f","g","h"}, it should e c = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"}  (but it in multidimensional array). thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can't just "add" two arrays, because the '+' operator is not defined for arrays; you need two nested `for` loops:

```
string[,] c = new string[27, 27];
for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 27; j++)
    {
        c[i, j] = a[i, j] + b[i, j];
    }
}
```

---

OK, I misunderstood your question...

This should work:

```
string[,] c = new string[54, 27];
for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 27; j++)
    {
        c[i, j] = a[i, j];
        c[27 + i, j] = b[i, j];
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm, i mean string c = new string [54,27] not string c = new string [27,27]. how to solve this problem? thanks for answering my question :)

Comment: I updated my answer. Next time, try to ask your question more clearly ;)

Comment: okay :) thank you so much for the answer :) sorry if my question doesn't clear

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0;i<27;i++)
  for (int j=0;j<27;j++)
    c[i,j] = a [i,j] + b[i,j];
```

Comment: hmm, i mean string c = new string [54,27] not string c = new string [27,27]. how to solve this problem? thanks for answering my question :)

Comment: ups, then you shuld use `a.CopyTo` and `b.CopyTo` but I've never used it. I hope someone else can help you.